# android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: when using 2 product flavors?

Tags: java, android

I have 2 product flavor. Let's say the example like this:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
      applicationId 'com.free.android'

    }
    premium {
      applicationId 'com.premium.android'

    }
```

My problem is when i use

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ExpiryListActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ExpiryListActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
```

The problem happened when `stackBuilder.addParentStack(ExpiryListActivity.class)`
The first app which used the productFlavor free doesn't cause `android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException` error.
But the second app which used the productFlavor premium it causes `android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException`. 
Then i read the docs that `stackBuilder.addParentStack(<Class>)` Add the activity parent chain as specified by manifest . How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**
change your metadata as

```
<meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="originalPackageName.ui.MainActivity" />
```

The basic problem is that gradle is expanding the package name for the parent activity class that you wrote in the metadata.

In case of your free product flavor it tries to find a class at location **com.free.android.ui.MainActivity**

And in case of your paid flavor it tries to find a class at location **com.premium.android.ui.MainActivity**

But gradle actually does not restructure the packages when you mention different applicationId's for your product flavors and the class is still located at **originalPackageName.ui.MainActivity** and hence the NameNotFoundException

where **originalPackageName** is a placeholder for the package name you started your project with.

Comment: Hi @Aashrai Ravoouro. Thanks for your answer. At first, i also thought like that. But, i can't have two manifests.

Comment: Hmm how about using [manifest placeholders](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Placeholder-support) then

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Aashrai Ravooru I never used those. But thanks for your reference. Looking up for it!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like i found it. On AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.ExpiryListActivity"
            android:label="@string/voucher_expiry_list"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.Slidable" >
          <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ui.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

I replace the meta-data name by:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.ExpiryListActivity"
            android:label="@string/voucher_expiry_list"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.Slidable" >
          <meta-data
            android:name=".ui.ExpiryListActivity"
            android:value=".ui.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

It works, but when pressing back it cannot return to MainActivity. But, I know if this is not the best solution. Please let me know if there is another better solution.
NB: This seems only happened on Android Lollipop (5.0)